# How to breakdown components in a multi page ReactJs application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJs, what would be the best way to breakdown the component hierarchy in a multi-page application ? For an example take an application with two columns. Left most column is the side bar and the right most column is for loading different views.

One view flow would be as follows. Side bar contains a link to view a list of products. Once the link is clicked a set of product with brief descriptions would be loaded into the right hand column.

If the user selects a specific product, the a full detailed view of that product would be loaded in the same panel replacing the original list view.

Now does that full detailed view component comes under the product list component as it's loaded by clicking on a product or is it better to keep it as a child component of the main application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at 'Thinking in React' link which kind of goes over the same theory on what you are asking which is how do i breakdown my components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

You should put your data where you have to click/or triggering an event that will make your data change.  In this case you would have to click on a link to trigger a product list, then click on the product to trigger product description.

You should not go more than 1 layer deep if you are passing state so don't pass it from parent to child to child.  If this is the scenario you should move your state lower.

I hope this gets you going and thinking towards the right path.